# Combining two Count Queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have theses two queries

```
SELECT course,
COUNT(*) AS countp 
FROM table1 
WHERE pickout='Yes' 
GROUP BY course

SELECT course,
COUNT(*) AS countw
FROM table1
WHERE pickout='Yes' AND result='Won'
GROUP BY course
```

what I am trying to achieve is a table with three columns `Course`, `Countp`, `Countw` but I am having trouble combining the two into one query.

Basically I am looking for a list of course with number of picks and then number of wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL the result of conditions evaluate to `1` or `0`. You can sum that up

```
SELECT course, 
       sum(pickout='Yes') AS countp,
       sum(pickout='Yes' AND result='Won') AS countw
FROM table1 
GROUP BY course
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
Course,
COUNT(*) AS CountP,
SUM(CASE WHEN result='Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountW
FROM table1
WHERE pickout = 'Yes'
GROUP BY Course
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.course,a.countp ,b.countw  from (SELECT course, COUNT(*) AS countp FROM table1 WHERE pickout='Yes' GROUP BY course)a full join 
(SELECT course, COUNT(*) AS countw FROM table1 WHERE pickout='Yes' AND result='Won' GROUP BY course)b
a.course=b.course
```